# Should I make this model seperate objects or 1 mesh

Tags: modeling, rigging

I'm modelling a humanoid character made of both solid and flexible parts joined together.

To avoid problems when rigging should the objects be joined together then weight painted to get the desired result, or is there a better way?

I have joints like the one below all over my model, should the flexible part be connected to one, both, or neither of the solid parts?
[image: Example]

Comment: join everything in the same object, it's the weight you'll give to each part that will make the mesh look flexible or solid, if a mesh is controlled by only one bone, it won't be stretched, therefore it will appear solid

Comment: Thanks for your help